# Iframe Youtube video showing black screen using DialogFragment and only audio is playing in Webview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am parsing iframe youtube link data using JSON to Webview in a Dialog Fragment. Video output is showing a black screen and only the audio of the video is playing. I have tried to use (android:hardwareAccelerated="true") in the manifest file and as well as programmatically in java code but it did not work for me.

If I use the Same in an Activity instead of a DialogFragment then I am getting the output result of the video and everything is working fine for me but for some reason, I need to play youtube video only in a Dialog Fragment. How to do this please help and here is my code below.

```
public class Activity extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        String frameVideo = "<html><body>Youtube video .. <br> <iframe width="320" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/lY2H2ZP56K4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

        WebView mwebView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            });
        displayVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                return false;
            }
        });
        mwebView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(getActivity().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath());
            mwebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mwebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
            mwebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
       //   mwebView.setInitialScale(1);
       //   mwebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


           if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {

           mwebView.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
            }
          mwebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);

         mwebView.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        mwebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        mwebView.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked your code and it's fine. I commented `setLayerType` property and checked. It's working fine. Just comment `mwebView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);`.