# Youtube videos shown black screen in webView when click on play button

Tags: java, android, android-webview, youtube-iframe-api

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.loadUrl(String.valueOf("https://techx.pk/youtube-videos/"));

webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
  public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return false;
  }
});
```

It only plays a video but showing a black screen.

Comment: I tried this. it only plays a video but showing a **black** screen.

Comment: Possibly related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54033035/iframe-youtube-video-showing-black-screen-using-dialogfragment-and-only-audio-is?rq=1

Comment: but that was not the solution

Comment: if you found a solution to your problem, you may post it as an answer if you think that may help other people.

Comment: I found it. the real cause is in the manifest file.
just remove these lines from the _application_ tag.
**android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:largeHeap="true"**
and done.
Youtube videos not showing a black screen anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Remove these Lines from the application tag.
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
in menifest and remove these lines in code

```
    webview.getSettings().setUserAgentString(webview.getSettings().getUserAgentString().replace("; wv", ""));
    webview.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
    webview.setLayerType(WebView.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    webview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```