# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac Android App Webview Not Playing Youtube Video

Tags: android, xamarin, video

I am writing a cross platform XForms app for iOS and Android. I have an embedded WebView control in the xaml. I am passing in a URL that is a page that has YouTube video links on it.

When I run the app on iOS either a real device or simulator everything works fine.

When I run the app on Android either a Pixel 2 with Android 10, the audio plays but there is no video. It is just a black screen.

I am using VS2019 for Mac and targeting api 29.

I do get some interesting output in the debug window:

```
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
[] PlayerBase::PlayerBase()
[cr_MediaCodecBridge] create MediaCodec video decoder, mime video/avc
[] TrackPlayerBase::TrackPlayerBase()
[libOpenSLES] Emulating old channel mask behavior (ignoring positional mask 0x3, using default mask 0x3 based on channel count of 2)
[OMXClient] IOmx service obtained
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706433 for video/avc
[VideoCapabilities] Unrecognized profile 2130706434 for video/avc
[MediaCodec] MediaCodec will operate in async mode
[SurfaceUtils] connecting to surface 0x77fd67a010, reason connectToSurface
[MediaCodec] [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 10594305
[SurfaceUtils] disconnecting from surface 0x77fd67a010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
[SurfaceUtils] connecting to surface 0x77fd67a010, reason connectToSurface(reconnect)
[SurfaceUtils] set up nativeWindow 0x77fd67a010 for 426x240, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
[Gralloc3] allocator 3.x is not supported
[SurfaceUtils] set up nativeWindow 0x77fd67a010 for 432x240, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x20002900
[NdkImageReader] acquireImageLocked: Overriding buffer format YUV_420_888 to 0x7fa30c06.
[AudioManager] Use of stream types is deprecated for operations other than volume control
[AudioManager] See the documentation of requestAudioFocus() for what to use instead with android.media.AudioAttributes to qualify your playback use case
[chromium] [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(224)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
[chromium] [ERROR:web_contents_delegate.cc(224)] WebContentsDelegate::CheckMediaAccessPermission: Not supported.
[CameraManagerGlobal] Connecting to camera service
[cr_media] Requires MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS and RECORD_AUDIO. No audio device will be available for recording
```

Comment: there are many existing posts about Youtube in an Android webview - have you read any of them?  https://www.google.com/search?q=android+webview+youtube+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Actually I had done a lot of google searching. What I didn't do was search just stackoverflow. that was my mistake. I had read through several things. I guess my searching skills are just not as good as yours. If I filter your search by everything in the last year then the first answer was it. For others who find this it is the app settings in the androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

In the comments you can see that Jason gave a search for google. I took that search and limited it to 1 year and the top answer answered my question. Here it is:

[Youtube videos shown black screen in webView when click on play button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58112959/youtube-videos-shown-black-screen-in-webview-when-click-on-play-button)

It is the 5th comment talking about changing the AndroidManifest.xml:

"I found it. the real cause is in the manifest file. just remove these lines from the application tag. android:hardwareAccelerated="false" android:largeHeap="true" and done. Youtube videos not showing a black screen anymore. – Khadija Hameed Sep 26 '19 at 11:41"